# Installing .Net Core on Ubuntu server on VMware

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, vmware

In our company we want to code with .net core and make a cross-platform software. we have a 64-bit system (corei 2, 4G memory, windows 10) and VS2017, sql server 2016 and a vmware are installed on that. Also Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS has been installed on vm.

Installing Ubuntu desktop has taken a long time and not yet successful.we are going to install sql server 2017 and vscode on Ubuntu but not sure whether they can be installed or not. we have searched for minimum hardware requirements but not sure that these would be sufficient. Can anyone who has tested both environments help us. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once VS Code is a cross platform text editor, It will work properly on your Ubuntu. MSSQL 2017 is going to work properly as well, but it's important to point out that the released version is still in preview. The question I'd like to ask you is, It's really necessary to use MSSQL 2017? Couldn't it be MYSQL for instance?

Best regards